# local file cannot be reverted to clean copy from SVN

Tags: svn

I'm having a really weird problem with three files in my project. They're all PHP files which contain only two lines:

```
<php
require_once 'other file';
```

The files were previously symlinks, but they've been replaced in the repository with real PHP files, because symlinks don't work on Windows and my workstation OS is Windows 7 (local test environment).

The weird thing is that in the SVN the files are exactly that, but in `svn status` they show up as modified (`~`). If I try to `svn revert` them, the resulting file contains only `<php` and not the `require_once` line!
Same thing happens if I delete the files locally and svn update (tried --force too)/revert/cleanup. Nothing seems to help. What could be the deal with this and how to fix it?

Comment: try "svn cat <file_repo_url>". If result is the same then the last version is broken in the repository, in which case check the history and find the last good revision.

Comment: Also try `svn list` to check that the symlink isn't still present in the repository and causing a filename collision on your workstation.

Comment: `svn cat` shows what was expected (the PHP code), `svn list` - no duplicates.

Comment: Damn 5min timeout :@  Deleted the files from the SVN and committed them back again, it's fine now, but I would like to know WTF that was and why did it happen? The SVN cache was obviously updated so why would it think it was a different type of file?